# How do I input 3D array data in CPLEX?

Tags: arrays, 3d, cplex, opl

```
Set of inputs
int i=...; //set of origins
int j=...; //set of destinations
int t=...;//set of time periods
i=100;
j=100;
t=4;
```

How do I input these data in CPLEX? Cplex cannot read 3D arrays from excel. Is there any way I could tell CPLEX to read 3D array data from CPLEX?

Answer (score 0):

You can only read 2D arrays directly but with some tricks you can read from any dimension.

A very good tech note answers this:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/125333

And a small example from https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel

.mod

```
range A=1..2;
range B=1..3;
range C=1..4;


tuple someTuple{
    key int a;
    key int b;
    key int c;
    int value;
    };
    

{someTuple} someSet = ...;

int v[a in A][b in B][c in C]=item(someSet,<a,b,c>).value;

dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
    forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==v[a][b][c];
}


assert forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection sheet("write3Darray.xlsx");

someSet from SheetRead(sheet,"A1:D24");
```

Comment: hugexls.mod is 2D. I tried something similar with 3D but did not work. Thanks, anyways.